# How to fetch the IP address,subnet,gateway and dns servers from ipconfig /all using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, ip

I want to fetch IP address, subnet, gateway and DNS servers from **ipconfig** and store in a variable using bash script.
I have created below script but it is not fetching dns servers(below XXXX and YYYY) in separate variables.

```
                                  `DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : XXXX
                                                                       YYYY`
```

> echo IPAddress is:
> for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "IPv4"') do set ip=%%b 
> set ip=%ip:~1% 
> echo %ip%
>
> for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "Subnet"') do set     sub=%%b
> set sub=%sub:~1%
> echo Subnet is: 
> echo %sub%
>
> for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "Default"') do set gate=%%b 
> set gate=%gate:~1% 
> echo Gateway is:
> echo %gate%

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this :  [Get current DNS server used by using Batch code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190690/get-current-dns-server-used-by-using-batch-code?answertab=active#tab-top)

```
@echo off
rem clean variable
set "ip="
rem search data
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%f in ('echo exit^|nslookup 2^>nul') do ( @echo %%f & set "ip=%%f" )
rem remove spaces from variable
set "ip=%ip: =%"
echo DNS_ip = %ip%
pause
```